# Removing strings in wordpress using regex or wildcards in database

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have this string that should be removed from the content of my wordpress website. I want it to be removed from database too.Either via Phpmyadmin or through a plugin.
Plugins don't accept wildcards or regex.
The string starts with `<li class="dZip">` and ends with `Download ZIP</a></li>` , and contains alphanumeric and special characters between them. I like to remove all of them.
I have tried this `<li class="dZip">\b.*Download ZIP</a></li>\b` using plugins.No use.

Comment: Try this: SELECT * FROM table WHERE containing_field LIKE "<li%class\"dZip\">%Download%ZIP</a><li>"

Comment: It won't delete it. It will give you a chance to see what it is before deletion.

Comment: I have edited the question, there are many characters in between those two strings. And I need to remove it or replace with any other string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new enough MySQL or MariaDB, you can use the function `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

The regexp would be

```
<li class="dZip">.*?Download ZIP</a></li>
```

two changes from what you had...

- `\b` is a "word boundary".  By definition either side of `>` is a word boundary.
  So, I removed them.
- `.*` would gobble up all the way to the last `</li>`.  If you are expecting multiple li's then use `.*?` so that it gobbles only the one.  The function (either MySQL's `REGEXP_REPLACE` or PHP's `preg_replace`) will repeat until finished.